# Get number of generic type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Is there any way to get number of parameters in unbound generic type?
For example:

```
f(typeof(List<>))        => 1
f(typeof(Dictionary<,>)) => 2
```

**UPD**

I know about getting number from Type.Name but maybe there is a way to get from Type directly

Comment: What research have you done into the operation exposed by `Type` that might allow you to do this?

Comment: Terminology: the number of generic parameters a type accepts is called the `generic arity` of that type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already have the generic type definition. All you need to do is get the generic type arguments:

```
Type.GetGenericArguments().Length
```

**EDIT**:

As Sebastian noted, this may give you results that might be surprising if you're used to dealing with C#, because C# hides the generic type arguments that are "inherited". For example:

```
void Main()
{
  typeof(A<>.Nested<>).GetGenericArguments().Dump();
}

public class A<T>
{
  public class Nested<V>
  {

  }
}
```

will give you `{ typeof(T), typeof(V) }`. This is simply how the .NET class actually is - that's how you need to refer to it, how you'd create it through reflection etc.

This only matters if you're specifically trying to do something with the C# compiler in regards to classes not known at compile-time; which probably means you're trying to generate C# code. There doesn't seem to be any supported way of getting the behaviour C# has safely - you'll just have to use a real code generator instead of slapping strings together :)

Comment: Note that this may not work with **nested types**; e.g. for `OuterClass<,>.InnerClass<>` you will get `3`, not `1`.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski Well, that depends on what you want exactly. The inner class *does* have three generic type arguments, it's just that C# hides the ones "inherited" from the classes higher up. If you want to replicate the C# behaviour, you need to work a bit harder :)

Comment: @Luaan: +1. Regarding the last paragraph of your answer: Computing the number of "non-inherited" generic parameters of a nested type is actually fairly trivial (just another query and a subtraction away); see the second half of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025384/240733).

Answer (score 2):

[Luaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38702266/240733) doesn't work for nested types.

For example, if you have `OuterClass<,>.InnerClass<>` one would expect `1` argument - but .NET actually reports `3`.

The only way I found to solve this is to parse the name of the generic type definition like so:

```
public static int GetGenericParameterCount(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    var genericTypeDefName = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name;
    int tickIndex = genericTypeDefName.LastIndexOf('`');
    if (tickIndex == -1)
    {
        // This will happen for nested types like "OuterClass<int>.InnerClass".
        return 0;
    }

    return int.Parse(genericTypeDefName.Substring(tickIndex + 1), NumberStyles.None);
}
```

Comment: The nested class does have three generic type arguments. So unless you specifically want the same behaviour that the C# compiler has, three is the correct answer. The problem with parsing the type name is that the behaviour you're relying on isn't defined - the compiler can change the way the type name is generated whenever it wants, not to mention that other .NET languages have different conventions.

Comment: No need to parse strings. You can get the same number by starting with `type.GetGenericArguments().Length`, then in case of a nested type, subtract the same metric of the outer type (`type.DeclaringType`). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025384/240733).

Answer (score 1):

#### Computing the total number of generic parameters

Simply query `t.GetGenericArguments().Length` to find the total count of generic parameters (or arguments) of some type `t`:

```cs
static int GenericParameterCount(this Type t)
    => t.IsGenericType ? t.GetGenericArguments().Length
                       : 0;
```

#### Nested types only: Computing the number of "local" generic parameters (excluding those inherited from outer types)

Doing the above for a nested type might give results that are initially surprising. For example, type `Outer<T>.Inner` has 1 generic parameter, type `Outer<T>.Inner<U>` has 2. This can appear to be incorrect as long as you think of these nested types only as `Inner` or `Inner<U>` (i.e. the way they would be declared in source code).

(For the same reason, you might be initially surprised to find that `typeof(Outer<T>.Inner).IsGenericType == true`, even though the queried type `Inner` doesn't appear to be generic.)

If you really want to count only the "local" generic type parameters and exclude those inherited from its outer types, you can simply subtract the outer type's (`type.DeclaringType`) total number of generic parameters:

```cs
static int LocalGenericParameterCount(this Type t)
    => t.IsNested ? t.GenericParameterCount() - t.DeclaringType.GenericParameterCount()
                  : t.GenericParameterCount();
```